# How am I using this operator wrongly?

Tags: javascript

When `x.length` is *smaller* than or *equal* to **5** `yes` is returned.

But, when it is not `undefined`, is returned I thought It was supposed to return `no`

```js
function number(x) {
  if (x.length <= 5) {
    return (x ? 'yes' : 'no')
  }
}

console.log(number('Sam'));

console.log(number('Donald'));
```

Comment: When `x`'s length is under or equal to 5, *you return a result*. Otherwise you return no result at all.

Comment: if `x.length` is greater than `5` you don't go in the `if` statement at all. The default return value is `undefined` and that's what you get when you don't go through any other `return` statement in the function.

Answer (score 3):

```
function number(x) {
   return x.length <= 5 ? 'yes' : 'no';
}
```

Read more about [Ternary (conditional) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: Explanation: ? sign is used to check if the condition is true.  and : is used as else in above code. This is if else statement shorthand property. The asker should understand now

Comment: @philoczar ahem, it's actually called Ternary operator.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     function number(x){
        if (x.length <= 5){
            return "yes"
        } else {
            return "no"
        }
      }
```

or shorter:

```
function number(x){
   return x.length <= 5 ? "yes" : "no"
}
```

You don't have to add additional test `(x ? 'yes':'no')`

If you want to test if x is not undefined or null you can add it in the beggining like:

```
function number(x) {
  if(x && x.length) {
    if(x.length <= 5) {
      return "yes"
    } else {
      return "no"
    }
  } else {
    return "is not an array or doesn't exist"
  }
}
```

or shorter:

```
function number (x) {
  return x && x.length ? x.length <= 5 ? "yes" : "no" : "is not an array or 
     doesn't exist"
}
```

Comment: If you're doing this type check, you should `throw new TypeError` instead of returning some completely different string.

Comment: @deceze it depends what he want's to achieve, we don't know full code, maybe he just wants to inform user about it in some html element or something. Why do you assume he always wants to show new error?

Comment: Sure, it depends on the definition of what this function is supposed to do. But assuming the definition of the function is "return 'yes' or 'no' depending on whether the input is shorter than 5", then passing in a value which doesn't have a length is an *exception*. You'd need to extend the definition of the function's purpose to include "or an error message if the input has no length", which at the moment is not included.

Comment: @deceze if you want to give your answer just post your answer :)